# Where to find source of an Amazon EC2 compatible kernel

Tags: amazon-ec2, kernel, source

I have some issues with finding the source code of Amazon EC2 compatible kernels. There is a tutorial in Amazon EC2 documentation of how to run instances with custom kernels, but those must be from the Amazon EC2 compatible kernels. It is hard to find sources for the Amazon EC2 kernels though, according to this conversation:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ec2debian/OKDnCZQikEc

The following post explains how to compile a kernel from source and register it to EC2, but this kernel must be an Amazon EC2 compatible kernel, and the provided links to download it are broken:
http://alestic.com/2008/05/kernel-modules-2-6-21

I need to have the kernel from source in order to compile the OrangeFS kernel module.

So do you think that there is a place to find the source of an Amazon EC2 kernel?

Many thanks,
Dimos

Comment: Why not build it as a module?

Comment: To build the kernel as a module? How am I supposed to build it if I don't have its source?

Comment: You don't need the kernel's source, only its `-devel` package.

Comment: I don't think you can build OrangeFS kernel module when having just the -devel package:
http://orangefs.org/documentation/releases/current/doc/pvfs2-quickstart/pvfs2-quickstart.php#SECTION00060000000000000000

Comment: "Note that you can often find a kernel source tree (or a symlink to the right place) at /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build2. For example, if you were running the default Fedora 3 kernel (linux-2.6.9-1.667) you would find the kernel tree in `/lib/modules/2.6.9-1.667/build`." That path is created by `kernel-devel`, so I'd say it's fine.

Comment: The articles you reference (and which I wrote) are obsolete.  The standard today is to run an AKI that uses PV (paravirtualization).  The end result is that the kernel in your AMI boot disk is the true kernel that is run on the instance.  This means you can build and use your own kernel on EC2.  You should use the latest kernel source provided by your distro (Ubuntu, Amazon Linux, CentOS, Debian, etc.).  Note that there might be a special EC2 or cloud variation.

Comment: If you are using Amazon Linux, the kernel source should be available through the yum repository.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, the kernel source might be available in the linux-ec2 source package.

Comment: @EricHammond Your comments here should really be an answer.  They answer the question and they are authoritative.

Comment: @Ladadadada: I think the answer should have specific commands or URLs to access the kernel source.  I believe I provided general guidance, but didn't have the time to do the rest of the research.

Comment: @Eric: I think your answer is quite general and does not provide any hint for how to have an AKI that uses paravirtualization and how to specify your own custom kernel. Could you please give me some short hints about the procedure I need to have an Amazon VM with a custom kernel by the way you mention? Any recent documentation? This does not seem to work for me, as it requires to have an Amazon EC2 kernel:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedkernels.html

Comment: @Ignacio: the -devel package sounds ok, but still I cannot find the specific kernel version that is already running from any repository.

Answer (score 1):

Orangefs also available through the amazon marketplace 
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=f34f2eeb-dcc6-4e41-90e1-92fbd146db9f

it supports an automated deployment via cloud formation templates, easier than dealing with compiling the source.